# Is there no way to show additional disk space/capacity columns in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, monterey

One of the things MacOS simply doesn't seem to do is easily show size *and free space* on disk drives. It shows `size` in Finder if you go to your computer:

[image]

But it does not show the disk size or free space, only the amount it's using - no way to easily see (unlike Windows) how full a disk is.

I have enabled Status Bar but in my image above you can see it doesn't show me anything useful. Isn't it supposed to?

I know I can select an item and preview by pressing `Space` which is... OK. And I can show `Info` in another window but that's quite clunky. What I really want is to see "at a glance" the size and 'fullness' of *all* my drives at once.

Is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is List View, where you are "in" the top hierarchy shown, regardless of what is selected and how far you drill down.

If you double-click on "Macintosh HD", then you will be 'in' the internal system volume, and you will see the free space shown in the status bar.

[image]

The same behaviour occurs in Icon View, where it makes more sense, as you only see one level at a time.

If you choose Column View then the problem does not appear. Simply selecting the volume there will show you the free space.

[image]

If you want to see info for all your drives at once, then in Ventura, go to System Settings > General > Storage > All Volumes.
(In earlier versions, it was under "About This Mac".)